# Can't install using sudo apt-get - package lists... Error

Tags: ubuntu, installation, sudo, apt-get, apt

I am trying to install pyqt5 on my computer using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

But I am getting the following error below -

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/developer.download.nvidia.com_compute_machine-learning_repos_ubuntu1404_x86%5f64_en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` but the same error as above is coming up.

My OS is 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04lts.

How do I solve this problem, I am unable to understand why this error is coming up?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with the package to me. Have you checked if it has any other dependencies that need installing first?

EDIT: This looks like it can be installed using PIP I would recommend using that.